# MVC jquery mobile not taking full page width on load

Tags: css, html, jquery-mobile, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to MVC 4 and jquery mobile and have been developing a mobile optimized site.  The problem I am running into is when I have a mobile device horizontally, on page load the page will only take up about 3/4 of the screen.

If I rotate the screen to vertical and then back to horizontal, it then takes up the page width horizontally.  This happens frequently as I navigate through my site.

I have the following meta tag on my pages:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
```

I have searched as best I can for answers, but I'm having trouble coming up with search termsto even find this problem elsewhere.  Has anyone else run into this issue?  Using iPad 2 with IOS 6.0.1.  I apologize ahead of time if this is an easy fix or if it has been posted before.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: First are you talking about page (with header, content and footer) or just content?

Comment: The full page including header, content, and footer.  It's essentially a big block of black on the far right

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out after a day of playing around.  My meta tag had to be edited:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; minimum-scale=1.0; target-densityDpi=device-dpi" />
```

I took out the user-scalable because I found that with Android, it ignored the meta tag if that part of the content was in there.